# Change the CSS attribute if an option selected with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
<select>
    <option disabled selected>Select Method</option>
    <option value="question">Question</option>
    <option value="password">Password</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>
```

Now I want when user select each of them some div that hidden in css with `display:none;` get visible for example when user select Question the div that have question id get visible or when Password selected the div that have password id get visible.
I try this but not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#auth option:selected").text() ==  "question"){
        $("#question").css("display","block");
    }
});
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: Bind to the `change` event of the `<select>` element, for a start.

Comment: how is possible someone to select from disabled dropdown?

Comment: why is this disable already ?

Comment: where is the `#auth` element

Comment: Ops, I forget to edit the code, it enable when user click on a checkbook. I fixed it.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6qpb9oed/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$('#auth').on('change', function() {
    var that = $(this).val();
    if (that  ===  "question"){
        $("#question").css("display","block");
    }
});
```

Comment: @ale_x your welcome, you can upvote answer if it helped. Answer by Anoop Joshi is a good one though.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the pattern you have done so far, you have to write code for each option. If your options and div elements are coupled with value and id, you can simply do like this,

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $("div").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/413/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is Demo for this , remove disabled from select tag so that user can select the options

**Jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/z9gcf40r/2/

**Code**

**HTML**

```
<select id="showdiv">
    <option disabled selected>Select Method</option>
    <option value="question">Question</option>
    <option value="password">Password</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>

<div id="question" class="hide">
    <p>question</p>
</div>

<div id="password" class="hide">
    <p>password</p>
</div>

<div id="email" class="hide">
    <p>email</p>
</div>

<div id="none" class="hide">
    <p>none</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
    display:none
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("div").hide();
    $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better check value than the text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ($("#auth option:selected").val() ==  "question"){
            $("#question").css("display","block");
        }
    });
```